# Applications close on disconnect in server 2012

Tags: windows-server-2012, timeout

I have an application that I'd like to continue to run after disconnecting.  This is in a Windows server 2012 environment that I access via remote desktop connection.  Currently, it shuts down my applications after some specified time elapses after disconnecting.  I haven't figured out exactly how long that period is, but if I wait long enough and reconnect, the application has closed.  How can I prevent this?  My server manager doesn't seem to have the collections (see: http://www.tomshardware.com/answers/id-1936940/server-2012-rdp-auto-disconnect.html) or remote desktop services icons (another potential solution here: http://blogs.technet.com/b/askperf/archive/2012/10/30/windows-8-windows-server-2012-remote-desktop-management-server.aspx), so I cannot get to those properties.  My IT team is perplexed as well.

EDIT (additional information requested):
This software is SRCware v 0.2 (I don't have a high enough reputation to post the link).  It launches via an exe file.  I've run this app in several environments with no problem: RDP, Citrix XenApp, and VMware vShpere web client, all Windows server 2008 environments.  It's been quite a while, but very quickly one day, my IT team checked off a setting that prevented all of my apps from closing on disconnect.  I believe this was in Citrix.  No changes were necessary in the other environments.  Something is different about Server 2012, however.  Disconnecting leads to the app closing after an undetermined period of time.  My IT team suggested that I X out instead of disconnecting.  Here, I get a message that my programs will continue to run, and I can log in later and they will still be there, but that's not the case if I wait long enough.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of options based on the "type" of applications you are trying to keep running.  None of them will come without some knowledge of how Windows Server runs.

Due to the lack of info about "what", the following is a general guideline that you can use to further investigate:

OPTION 1:

Setup the applications to run as a Windows Service.  This can be achieved by opening up a CMD prompt using Elevated Permissions and using the following Syntax (Replace "CAPS" with your info:

```
sc create YOURSERVICEDISPLAYNAME binpath= C:\YOURSERVICE-EXECUTIBLE.EXE-OR-CMD-etc start= delayed-auto obj= DOMAIN-ACCOUNT-FOR-SERVICE-PERMISSIONS password= ACCOUNT-PASSWORD
```

NOTE:  This will not work to just launch an EXE for something like "Photoshop" as an example.  There is usually a script that is run with this that give the Executible, Command, or whatever the file is instructions on what to do.

OPTION 2:

Use the Windows Task Scheduler.  This is a bit easier than a service, in that you can setup some schedules to ensure that the software continually runs, or you can invoke it based on some "triggers" that you can customize.

Ultimately, it will be up to you to figure out what is best for your environment.  Without all the info, and knowing "what" you need, this is probably the best you will get.  Let me know if you have any additional info, and I can edit/add to this.  But for what you are asking, these are 2 viable options.

Comment: @JimCJulsonJr-thanks for your response.  Not sure what other info you need.  This is statistical software that may run for several hours at a time.  In other Windows operating environments, I've simply had to check off a box that said to keep applications running after disconnect.  There does not seem to be such an option in server 2012.  However, it sounds like the solutions you propose might work.  If you can be more specific about the type of additional information you need, I'll be glad to provide it.

Comment: No problem William.  So, knowing what the software does will dictate your options.  Since I'm not familiar with what the software is, or how it's launched, that's why I gave "generics".  You say that there's options to "keep the software running after disconnect".  Where exactly are you seeing that option in other versions?  That sounds like a Windows option the way you said it.  Are you saying you used to run RDP, launch your app, then let it run, and even if you got "disconnected", it still gave you data?  If so, this is an entirely different issue, and one with what should be easy to fix.

Comment: Oh, in addition to my post above this one, can I ask you the name of the software?  Is this software something that requires you to manually set configuration, then run, or do you just launch an EXE and off it goes...?

Comment: @JimCJulsonJr-edited question to try to provide a clearer picture of problem

Answer (score 0):

The answer from JimCJulsonJr describes better solutions than RDP for running applications in the background. What's left without answer is how to prevent these applications left in disconnected RDP session from shutting down after a certain amount of time.

If the Remote Desktop Services role is not installed, you can't change the settings as described in the [Windows Server 2012: Remote Desktop Management Server](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2012/10/30/windows-8-windows-server-2012-remote-desktop-management-server/) article. Still, you can access your server through RDP for administrative purposes.

The timeout limits can be set via Group Policy. Both *Computer Configuration* and *User Configuration* has **Policies** > **Administrative Templates** > **Windows Components** > **Remote Desktop Services** > **Remote Desktop Session Host** > **Session Time Limits** with these settings:

- Set time limit for disconnected sessions
- Set time limit for active but idle Remote Desktop Services sessions
- Set time limit for active Remote Desktop Services sessions
- End session when time limit are reached

Just change these to *disabled* in the skope you want them to affect. Note that *default* for all these is *disabled* meaning there are no time limits, so they have been probably *enabled* somewhere else.